# Conditions for finiteness of group in geometric group theory

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Are there any sufficient conditions in geometric group theory for a group to be finite? Are there any necessary conditions?

Comment: What do you mean with geometric group theory? There are many ways and approaches to do geometric group theory. A rather boring condition would be for example that a Cayley graph has finitely many vertices (whereas boundedness would not be sufficient).

Comment: I was wondering if there are any non-trivial geometric properties that induce finiteness of the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often in Geometric Group Theory, we study a group by studying a space it acts on in a certain way.  A typical way we like groups to act on spaces is via a [geometric group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_group_action), that is, an action that is:

1. Properly Discontinuous
2. Cocompact
3. Via isometries

We typically want this action to be on a proper, geodesic metric space.  Such an action has a very simple description of when a group is finite:  If a finitely-generated group $G$ acts geometrically on a proper, geodesic metric space, then the group is finite if and only if the metric space is of finite diameter.